# "instance has no attribute 'iter'" not working from command line

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I recently started editing XML's using Python and I am still finding it quite tricky...

Now I finished my script and tested it first manually. It worked. 
Then I tried to run the script entirely but received an error that didn't occur before.

I provided a minimal example here:

```
import glob
import os
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

curgraph = "somefolder/somefolder/editedGraphPath_full.xml"   
tree = ET.parse(curgraph)
root = tree.getroot()
i=0
for file in root.iter('file'):
  i = i+1
  print i
```

If I run this line by line within Python everything is working just fine. However, if I run it over cmd line, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/somefolder/somefolder/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    for file in root.iter('file'):
AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'
```

I tried to use some the related questions an SO but I didn't find anything helpful yet.

Answer (score 2):

use `root.findall(..)`

```
import glob
import os
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

curgraph = "somefolder/somefolder/editedGraphPath_full.xml"   
tree = ET.parse(curgraph)
root = tree.getroot()
i=0
for file in root.findall('file'):
  i = i+1
  print i
```

Comment: But this doesn't search recursively through all child nodes of the XML right?

Comment: It actually works but you are required to define the exact position of the file node within your XML structure. 
I looked into `iter` in order to be Independent from knowledge about the structure